# How to intersect two lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog, intersection

I do this

a([1,3,5,2,4]).

b([6,1,2]).

issn(L):-intersection(a,b,L).

why do I get false?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found it!

a([1,3,5,2,4]).

b([6,1,2]).

issn(L):-
    a(D),
    b(G),
    intersection(D,G,L).